# Use CSS to hide an element in a Widget

Tags: css

I'm trying to hide the element **LEVERING: YES** within the results, after using the zipcode checker in the menu of the website https://graphicfish.nl/kaasboersiebren/. Use *8494* for a test and you can see the words I'm talking about.

Can it be hidden by using a dark overlay? Or minimizing its dimensions?

Which CSS code should I use specifically for this?

When I'm using this code obviously everthing is gone:

```css
.sidebar_zip_code_checker_success {
   display: none;
}
```

Comment: try giving it span and the set display none or visibility hidden

Comment: `.zip-code-submit + .sidebar_zip_code_checker_success`. Next time, please create a snippet with the relevant code. :)

Comment: @AmauryHanser it worked, thank you very much. I'm new to this forum i struggled with how to show the code right. Sorry but thanks!

Comment: you can use visibility : hidden or opacity : 0